# How to Integrate krpano to show panoramic images in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, panoramas

I want to show panoramic images in ios app.I found  krpano is solution for that but i don't know how to integrate krpano in IOS app.Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is loading the krpano panorama from a url using a Web View object.

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://linktoyourpanorama.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[[self paginaWeb] loadRequest:requestObj];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: it doesn't work if the KRPano panorama is loaded from inside the iOS project